# Has John Stewart ever worn a mask to conceal his identity?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, episode-identification, green-lantern

[John Stewart](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/John_Stewart) was the fourth Green Lantern of Earth, formerly a sniper for the U.S. Marines ([Prime Earth](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/John_Stewart_(Prime_Earth))) and an architect ([New Earth](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/John_Stewart_(New_Earth))). In his origin story, when Hal Jordan presents Stewart with the Green Lantern ring and explains about the Corps, John Stewart immediately rejects the mask to conceal his identity by saying:

> ***This black man lets it all hang out! I've got nothing to hide.***

[image: Hal Jordan begins Stewart's field training]
 <sub>*Green Lantern* Issue #87, 1971</sub>

Although this has been the case in every depiction of John Stewart's Green Lantern, I definitely remember seeing him wearing a mask (like Hal Jordan's) one time.

---

Some details that could help narrow down the search. The issue:

- is definitely Silver Age era and the art is definitely old
- is prior to the New-52 and Rebirth times
- has John Stewart drawn with hair (as in the image above) and not bald/shaved head as he's depicted now.
- **This may be helpful too**: there was a female Green Lantern character with him (I don't remember who but it was definitely another GL and was a female)

Can anyone help me find this issue/storyline where Stewart wore a mask?

Comment: I read it quite some time ago. I have wager with a friend and I don't wanna lose :P

Comment: Does Hal Jordan wear a mask to conceal his identity? ;)

Comment: If your bet with your pal still holds, you can tell them to cash up. See [RDFozz's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/188575/98028) and the conversation we had in the comments, he nailed it :p

Answer (score 3):

John Stewart became the backup Green Lantern for sector 2418 in *Green Lantern/Green Arrow* #87 (1971). Years later, when Hal Jordan decided to retire as Green Lantern, the Guardians of the Universe chose John to take on the role as the active Green Lantern, as Hal (and readers) discovered in *Green Lantern* (1960) #182, cover dated November 198.

From issue 182 through 187, his real identity was unknown. John chose to reveal it publicly in *Green Lantern* #188, cover dated May 1985 (the splash page of which was seen in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/188546)), and stopped wearing the domino mask at that point.

Note that these stories lead into the issues of *Green Lantern* that were tightly tied into *Crisis on Infinite Earths*, which saw another resident of Earth and former backup GL, Guy Gardner, get a power ring, and saw Hal un-retire, giving us three active GLs from Earth.

Aside: the female Green Lantern mentioned was probably Katma Tui, who John met in *Green Lantern* 182, and who he became involved with by the time the title changed to "Green Lantern Corps" with issue #201. They were together until her death a few years later.

The two of them together in issue #188:

[image: John and Katma Tui discussing together]

Answer (score 2):

Found [this website](https://majorspoilers.com/2013/02/17/hero-history-green-lantern-john-stewart/) which has the splash page of *Green Lantern* #188 (1985).

[image: John Stewart's Green Lantern identity revealed]